# Update key in redis in nodejs

Tags: node.js, redis, backend

We have Redis Client.set() and Redis Client.get() how to update a key rather than deleting and setting again?
Is there any function in Redis Nodejs library?

Comment: that's what `set` does, update if exists - create if it doesn't.

Comment: I thought it just creates..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suppose my redis key stored like below

```
{"User":{"id":9134},"UserRule":{"access":1}}
```

First we need to fetch redis data using key and after that we will update accordingly

```
const { redisServer} = require('redisConfig');

const redisClient = redisServer();
  redisClient.get(`${key}`, async (err, result) => {
    let userData = JSON.parse(result);
    userData.UserRule.access = 0;
    redisClient.setex(`${key}`, 7776000, JSON.stringify(userData));
  })
```